# for-each in XSLT for image

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a for-each statement in my XSLT for checking if there are more than one product image .if more than one then show the images.here I need another condition with this is I only need to show 4 images.how can include this into my for-each statement.now my for-each statement is like.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$extraimages/productimages/productimage[position() &gt; 1  and extension != '.pdf']">
    <li>
        Something to do
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$extraimages/productimages/productimage[position() &gt; 1  and position() &lt;= 5 and extension != '.pdf']">
    <li>
        Something to do
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to check whether there is more than one image.  When there are zero or one then show nothing, when there is more than one then show (up to) the first four?  Then how about

```
<xsl:if test="count($extraimages/productimages/productimage) &gt; 1">
  <xsl:for-each select="($extraimages/productimages/productimage)[position() &lt;= 4]">
    <li>something</li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

The parentheses make a difference if there is more than one `productimages` element in `$extraimages` - with the parentheses you'll get no more than four images, without them you'd get all `productimage` elements that are within the first four `productimage` children of their respective `productimages` parent element, which may be more than four in total.

You also have an `extension` check in your example in the question, to incorporate that you would do something like

```
<xsl:if test="count($extraimages/productimages/productimage[extension != '.pdf']) &gt; 1">
  <xsl:for-each select="($extraimages/productimages/productimage[extension != '.pdf'])[position() &lt;= 4]">
    <li>something</li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

again the parentheses may or may not be necessary depending on the structure of `$extraimages`.

If you want to show images 2-5 instead of 1-4 then you don't need the `if`, it just becomes

```
<xsl:for-each select="
       ($extraimages/productimages/productimage[extension != '.pdf'])
       [position() &gt; 1][position() &lt;= 5]">
  <li>something</li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

because the `select` will select nothing at all if there are fewer than two non-pdf images.